# Assign_attributes only assigns child attr_accessor values if a table column is changed on updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attr-accessor

Here's the set up

```
class Order
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :order
  attr_accessor :discount # this is NOT a table column, just a virtual attribute I want to be able to assign
end
```

Let's say I have an existing order `@order`. I noticed that if I were to try to assign `discount` on the child `Item` from the `Order` model, this only works if some other attribute on the child `Item` is changed.

```
@order.assign_attributes({"items_attributes"=>[{"id"=>40, "discount"=>"test"}]})
@order.items.first.discount
=> nil

@order.assign_attributes({"items_attributes"=>[{"id"=>40, "discount"=>"test", "admin_notes"=>"hello"}]})
# where admin_notes is a table column for Item
@order.items.first.discount
=> "test
@order.items.first.admin_notes
=> "hello"
```

Is there a quick setting change or something to change this? I'd like `attr_accessor` attributes to always be assigned even if no attributes are changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW if anyone stumbles upon this.... it appears to have resolved itself. Was working on something else today and noticed that I can't duplicate the original error anymore. A lot has changed in code, not going to go back and dig into this to figure out what happened. I do know that key configuration variables that could have affected this have not changed, e.g., `inverse_of` flag set on both models, `Order` model set to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`

Answer (score 0):

I see that your original question asked to be able to use `attr_accessor`, however it doesn't seem possible. I was able to get this working only by removing `attr_accessor`.

It appears that `attr_accessor` actually has the opposite behavior of making an attribute inaccessible instead of allowing it when using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Perhaps a bug? The docs do not provide any examples. As long as you are doing `params.permit` on the Controller-side, this is still safe to use without `attr_accessor`.

```rb
class Order
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Calling it from Rails console:

```rb
@order = Order.find(1)
@order.assign_attributes({"items_attributes"=>[{"id" => 1, "discount_cents" => "234"}]})
@order.save

#  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1 AND "items"."id" = $2  [["order_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
#   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
#  Item Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "items" SET "discount_cents" = $1 WHERE "items"."id" = $2  [["discount_cents", 234], ["id", 1]]
# => true
#   (5.8ms)  COMMIT

@order.assign_attributes({"items_attributes"=>[{"id" => 1, "discount_cents" => "789"}]})
# => nil
#  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1 AND "items"."id" = $2  [["order_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
@order.items.first.attributes
# => {"order_id"=>1, "id"=>1, "discount_cents"=>789}
```

Hope that provides a solution to your question :)

Comment: sorry if not clear, i am only looking to assign attributes, not to save them

Comment: @james ah ok changed my answer then

Comment: That doesn't work, that causes `@order.items` to return `nil` since the children `Items` that would normally be accessible on the parent `Order` are now overwritten by the `attr_accessor :items`

Comment: @james checkout this solution. I recreated the app locally and it appears to work

Comment: @james Ah I see you want to do this with `attr_accessor` but from what I can tell, it's not allowing this when you're using a nested relationship. Definitely seems like a limitation or even bug with rails. I'm guessing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` uses a different assignment mechanism

Comment: yes because without `attr_accessor` what happens is that `discount` has to be a table column right?

Comment: Ah so `discount` is not a table column? I didn't realize that. That would affect it I'm sure because items_attributes is most likely dynamically generated by `a.n.a.f.` based on columns

Comment: @james You seem pretty experienced, might I suggest using a "def items_attributes(*args); super(*args); ... end;" and overriding the original method? You could make it dynamic (to work for any attribute) or if it's just a one-off thing, you could add `discount = ...` inside that function.

Comment: I ended up just iterating through items and assigning attributes that way, instead of from the parent. it is kind fo just a one-off so i think it's fine like that =)